# Spring security ApplicationListener doesn't get called for AuthenticationSuccessEvent

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

In my security application, Spring security ApplicationListener doesn't get called for AuthenticationSuccessEvent

```
@Component
public class LoginListener implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event)
    {
        log.info("Login success");
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you configured this class as an `authentication-success-handler` either in your XML configuration or in your code?

Comment: No. As per my knowledge, this class is just a listener. `authentication-success-handler`r class is a different thing. Should it be an `authentication-success-handler` to work as expected?

Comment: You still need to register this as a bean. So this should either be added `explicitly` or should be in the `component-scan` path. Is this in the `component-scan` path?

Comment: Yes, it is in `component-scan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `xml` based mvc configuration and I was initializing my `security` like this:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

I solved above mentioned problem by:
Remove java based initialization and initialize it by adding filter `springSecurityFilterChain` in `web.xml`.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also, I was getting bean wiring exception whenever I was trying to `@Autowire` any bean in my `SecurityConfig` class. That problem also solved.